# retrieve variables from cog class

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.players = {}

    async def destroy_player(self,ctx):
        try:
            self.players.pop(ctx.guild.id)
            print(self.players)
        except:
            pass


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Music(client))
```

this is a part of my code. how can I use self.players outside the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, use the `get_cog` method. Assuming you are using this in another cog

```py
async def get_something(self, ctx): #this would be a cog method (command or any function inside a cog class)
   Music = self.bot.get_cog('Music')
   print(Music.players)
```

or if you are just using `bot`

```py
async def get_something(ctx):
   Music = bot.get_cog('Music') #or ctx.bot.get_cog('Music')
```

this will work if you have added the cog `Music` with `add_cog(Music(bot)`

### References:

- [get_cog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_cog#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_cog)
- [Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context.bot)

### Examples:

You can see the discord.py's docs example [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html?highlight=cogs#using-cogs)

Comment: Thank You! This helped me, but I don't know why, but had to use ctx instead of self:
Music = ctx.bot.get_cog('Music')

but it was still helpful!

Comment: Yeah, self only works if you are in a cog. I'll edit my answer for it to work in the main

Answer (score 1):

You can define a variable to store the class object before using it, like this:

```
def setup(client):
    c = Music(client)
    client.add_cog(c)
    print(c.players)
```

Comment: and how can I use 'c' outside the function?

Comment: because 'c.players' is a class, which I want to destroy. for that i need 'c' otherwise i need a way to kill the class by itself.

Comment: @AlpacaTheUnicorn You can add `return c` at the end of the function, and when you call the functin, instead of just `setup()`, you do `c = setup()`.

Comment: setup is called by `load_extension`, if I am not wrong. I don't think OP manually calls it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create the instance of a class (create instance outside of a function to use it outside of a function or in a function with return statement) which is a much simpler approach

Or if you want to avoid creating the instance of a class do sth like this:

```
class Music:
    players = {}

    @classmethod
    def get_players(self): 
        return self.players

Music.get_players()
```

This will also return the attribute without creating the class instance, but the attribute can be within **init** statement.

If you want to learn more read about getter and setter in Python

Comment: This will just return a new object, the cog's data will not be used, just the empty players will be printed always